# How to assign to a local variable in an anonymous function in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

I want to find the prime factors of a number. I wrote:

```
defmodule Prime do
  def factors(n) when is_integer(n) and n > 1 do
    Stream.unfold(n, fn 1 -> nil; n -> &({&1, div(n, &1)}).(lf n) end) |> Enum.to_list
  end

  def lf(n) when is_integer(n) and n > 1 do
    if rem(n, 2) == 0 do 2
    else Stream.iterate(3, &(&1 + 2)) |> Stream.filter(&(rem(n, &1) == 0))
                                      |> Stream.take(1) |> Enum.to_list |> hd
    end
  end
end
```

The problem lies at line 3: in the anonymous function I have to return the tuple `{f, n / f}`, where `f` is the lowest factor of `n` and is calculated in the `lf` function. However, I don't want to compute it *twice* (I could do `{lf n, div(n, lf n)}`). I also tried to define a closure, but apparently it's not allowed.

The trick that I used doesn't even work.

How is it done?

Comment: You didn't ask but I'd be wary of using a lambda in that context.  Readability and comprehension are also issues you should be considering when writing code and a lambda there is going to be hard for someone to figure out when they maintain your code.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci Absolutely. I just used it as a last resort, and it didn't even work. I come from Python where lambdas can only contain a single expression, so I didn't think about assigning on another line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try assigning a local variable in your anonymous function? I added line breaks to make it more readable.

```
def factors(n) when is_integer(n) and n > 1 do
  Stream.unfold(n,
    fn 1 -> nil
       n -> local = lf n
            {local, div(n, local)}         
    end) |> Enum.to_list
end
```

By the way, you could shorten your `lf` function by using [`Enum.find`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Enum.html#find/3). (I'd also make `lf` a private function.)

```
defp lf(n) when is_integer(n) and n > 1 do
  if rem(n, 2) == 0 do 2
  else Stream.iterate(3, &(&1 + 2)) |> Enum.find(&(rem(n, &1) == 0))
  end
end
```

Comment: I didn't know that after `->` I could have multiple expressions. I'll try your solution, thanks!

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks a lot! I also didn't know about find!